# Dropdownlist SelectedIndexChanged not firing on aspx page

Tags: asp.net, html-select

I want to auto click the search button whenever user select a value from drop down list.

code snippet:

Added the event handler in `InitializeComponent()` :

```
this.ddltrim.SelectedIndexChanged += new     System.EventHandler(this.ddltrim_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

code:

```
private void ddltrim_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
        if(ddlStores.Items.Count ==1)
            btnSearch_Click("Search", null);
    }
```

In designer:

```
<asp:dropdownlist id=ddltrim width="100%" Runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" EnableViewState="True">    
<asp:ListItem Value="Select Submodel" Selected="True">
      Select SubModel
      </asp:ListItem></asp:dropdownlist>
```

But selectIndexChanged in not firing when i select any value from ddl.  Have to manually click the button search.

Comment: Can you please try binding the SelectedIndexChange event in Page_Init or Page_Load?

Comment: i have added with page_load but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<asp:dropdownlist id=ddltrim width="100%" Runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" EnableViewState="True" onselectedindexchanged="ddltrim_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Value="Select Submodel" Selected="True">Select SubModel</asp:ListItem>
```

Comment: Thanks but i have already added selectedindexchanged from code behind.

Comment: I saw it, but why you add it from the code behind, because you add it only once, and then you can also add it static in the designer

Comment: ok. actually the application is in .net 1.1, and its auto added the selectIndexChanged code behind. i will work ur way then

Comment: ok, did you tried the answer from jbbi which add the event in the PreInit phase ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your add event code in Page_PreInit method

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ddltrim.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.ddltrim_SelectedIndexChanged);
}
```

Comment: tried but still not working. but when i click search button manually it goes to the ddltrim_SelectedIndexChanged fucntion first. Is it right?